# React-Native component either not rendering or rendering with the wrong props

Tags: react-native

I have two components that I'm trying to render:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import PositiveMetrics from './PositiveMetrics';
import PositiveNews from './PositiveNews';

const PositiveDashboard = props => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <PositiveMetrics />
      <PositiveNews />
    </View>
  );
};

export default PositiveDashboard;
```

and

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import NegativeMetrics from './PositiveMetrics';
import NegativeNews from './PositiveNews';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class NegativeDashboard extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
        }}
      >
        <NegativeMetrics />
        <NegativeNews />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default connect()(NegativeDashboard);
```

I want to reference my components in the component below; however, when I do, it renders only the positive dashboard (unless I rip out the subcomponents as shown below):

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {
  Container,
  Header,
  Tab,
  Tabs,
  TabHeading,
  Text,
} from 'native-base';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import PositiveMetrics from './PositiveMetrics';
import NegativeMetrics from './NegativeMetrics';
import NegativeNews from './NegativeNews';
import PositiveNews from './PositiveNews';

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header hasTabs />
        <Tabs>
          <Tab
            heading={
              <TabHeading>
                <Text>Positive Sentiment</Text>
              </TabHeading>
            }
          >
            /* I want to render PositiveDashboard in place of what's 
            below */
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                justifyContent: 'center',
              }}
            >
              <PositiveMetrics />
              <PositiveNews />
            </View>
          </Tab>
          <Tab
            heading={
              <TabHeading>
                <Text>Negative Sentiment</Text>
              </TabHeading>
            }
          >
            /* I want to render NegativeDashboard in place of what's 
            below */
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                justifyContent: 'center',
              }}
            >
              <NegativeMetrics />
              <NegativeNews />
            </View>
          </Tab>
        </Tabs>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    negativeNews: state.top5NegativeStories,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard);
```

I'm new to react-native so apologies if this question is too simple. Trying to understand why I'm unable to render my PositiveDashboard and NegativeDashboard component (both rely on redux store). Link my github repo is below if that helps.

Github Repo: https://github.com/aludwin1/pulse

Comment: Can you please explain what you trying to build with these react-native components! then i can help you very quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your NegativeDashboard component, you are trying to import NegativeMetrics and NegativeNews from the wrong files (probably due to a copy and paste from the PositiveDashboard component). To fix the issue, change these imports

```
import NegativeMetrics from './PositiveMetrics';
import NegativeNews from './PositiveNews';
```

to

```
import NegativeMetrics from './NegativeMetrics';
import NegativeNews from './NegativeNews';
```